# Strange alert when navigating through map google api v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

a strange problem is happening to me. When I load the map this alert appears im my map:

```
Dados do mapa
Dados cartográficos ©2012 Google, MapLink
```

I'm Brazilian so in english this alert would be:

```
Map Data
Cartographic data ©2012 Google, MapLink
```

This think started recently... about 3 or 4 days. I don't know what i can do to solve this problem... Anyone can help me?

If this help: Firebug detect that the domain of this alert is: `maps.googleapis.com`

My application include google api as this:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm putting another question here because i can't find an google support e-mail to talk about the alert that they put on api v3 when someone violate the terms of use of google.

I was reading the problem and I'm really not violating the terms of use, cause I'm trying to up the application in my local machine like a test, and I'm still getting the alert. I don't want to violate the google code to put off the alert so I realy need to talk with the supporters to solve the problem. Anyone has the e-mail of any supporter, I realy need to solve this problem.

Thank you very much for your time.

Heitor Polizeli Rodrigues Brazilian Student in Cience Computer UNESP - 3º Year - 5 semester

Comment: So you want the notice to appear in English?

Comment: Hello Lilina, no I just showed it in english to everyone read what is happening with my app. I just want to remove this alert. I read in somewheres that this is a bug in openlayers... but i'm not sure... This is the reason I need a google supporter e-mail. Thank you for your time

Comment: If you're using Openlayers in your code I do not know how to help you, sorry. I've never seen this alert with regular Google Maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a large notice on top of the map, like this...?

[image]

Normally this means that you have obscured the Terms of Use or copyright links, or the Google logo. It *may* indicate that Google have detected you're using the Free API on an internal network.

Comment: Thanks Andrew!! I will read the Terms of Use of API v3. I don't know if i could violate the terms of use... I just use the google API with openlayers in a web application. When I up the application with netbeans on tomcat, i have this alert... Could this kind of use violate the terms of use?

Comment: Possibly. Google don't publish details of their detection mechanisms for obvious reasons.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew... I will try to search how to use the google API in a correct way, to avoid this kind of problem.